# Best way of creating an IF statement based on the what button was clicked last

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-button, buttonclick

I have a Button that has a few IF statements that change its function depending on which Toggle button is checked. All this is working fine. 
I now want to create a statement that will change functionality depending on whether a certain button is clicked before it. Any ideas would be great.

Heres the code i have so far for the button

// YellowButton

```
    player1Counter= 0;
    player2Counter= 0;
    breakCounter= 0;
    yellowAdd2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yellowButton);
    player1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.player1Button);
    player2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.player2Button);
    player1ScoreDisplay= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1Score);
    player2ScoreDisplay= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player2Score);
    breakDisplay= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.breakCounterNum);

    yellowAdd2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (toggle1.isChecked()) {
        if (player1.isChecked()) {
            player1Counter += 2;
            breakCounter += 2;
            player1ScoreDisplay.setText("" + player1Counter);
            breakDisplay.setText("" +breakCounter);
        }
        if (player2.isChecked()) {
            player2Counter += 2;
            breakCounter += 2;
            player2ScoreDisplay.setText("" + player2Counter);
            breakDisplay.setText("" +breakCounter);
        }
    }
    if (toggle2.isChecked()) {
        if (player1.isChecked()) {
            breakCounter = 0;
            breakDisplay.setText("" +breakCounter);
            player1.setChecked(false);
            player2.setChecked(true);
            toggle2.setChecked(false);
            toggle1.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (player2.isChecked()) {
            breakCounter = 0;
            breakDisplay.setText("" +breakCounter);
            player2.setChecked(false);
            player1.setChecked(true);
            toggle2.setChecked(false);
            toggle1.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
    if (toggle3.isChecked()) {
        if (player1.isChecked()) {
            breakCounter = 0;
            breakDisplay.setText("" +breakCounter);
            player1.setChecked(false);
            player2.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (player2.isChecked()) {
            breakCounter = 0;
            breakDisplay.setText("" +breakCounter);
            player2.setChecked(false);
            player1.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
    if (toggle4.isChecked()) {
        if (player1.isChecked()) {
            player2Counter += 4;
            player2ScoreDisplay.setText("" + player2Counter);
            breakCounter = 0;
            breakDisplay.setText("" +breakCounter);
            player2.setChecked(true);
            player1.setChecked(false);
            toggle4.setChecked(false);
            toggle1.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (player2.isChecked()) {
                 player1Counter += 4;
                 player1ScoreDisplay.setText("" + player1Counter);
                 breakCounter = 0;
                 breakDisplay.setText("" +breakCounter);
                 player1.setChecked(true);
                 player2.setChecked(false);
                 toggle4.setChecked(false);
                 toggle1.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Unrelated, but it sure seems like there's some easy refactoring to be done here.

Comment: How would you have done it. Im learning and I know its not as clean and efficient as it can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a flag when the button is pressed:

```
boolean preButtonWasPressed = false;
// snip

// snap
preButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        preButtonWasPressed = true;
    }
});
```

and later on check this flag:

```
if ( preButtonWasPressed ) {
    // do some stuff
    // clear the flag
    preButtonWasPressed = false;
}
```

alternatively, you can change the `onClickListener` if a button is pressed:

```
changeBehaviorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        yellowAdd2.setOnClickListener(aDifferentOnClickListener);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Ill give these methods a try and get back to you on the results.